# list of dates to use in a script

Tags: sql-server

Is it possible to define a list of dates (for example: 19122016, 26122016, 01012017, 08012017) which every combinations of dates(like: [19122016, 08012017]) would be selected as 'first_date' and 'secound_date' to perform script?

```
declare @last_date varchar(10), @previous_date varchar(10), @sql varchar(max);
set @last_date ='20170115';
set @previous_date = '20170108';
set @sql = 'select *
into umkp.dbp.rosk_'+@last_date+'_seg
from umkp.dbp.rosk_'+@previous_date+'_seg'
```

And as a result would be a list of tabels created.

Comment: Why are you doing this instead of simply partitioning the table? Or at least use a `UNION` query over all tables? The optimizer will only scan the correct table if there is a constraint on the date table. Partitioning though is a LOT easier. It's available in all editions with 2016 SP1 ([even Express and LocalDb](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlreleaseservices/sql-server-2016-service-pack-1-sp1-released/))

Comment: Actually, I do not need table partitioning.I have some dated (in their names) databases, which would be a source for a script to produce new tables with calculations based on every combination of dates range. Sorry, maybe I don't understand what you mean, I'am a beginner with sql server:(

Comment: It's very unclear to me what you are asking for - you seem to be cloning tables. Also how are you arriving at a combination (paring?) of [19122016, 08012017] and why isn't this combination carried into you query?

Comment: The script is very big to put here and stole your time, so I put some part of it. The main problem is that in a script I many times use different table names with dates iether as source or as output. It's not convenient to change dates every time and run again script, because it near 72 date points in a range.

Answer (score 0):

Create a table, or table-variable to hold the dates pairs. Then use that table to create a select into-statement for each row in the table.

```
DECLARE @dates TABLE(last_date varchar(10), previous_date varchar(10));
INSERT @dates
        ( last_date, previous_date )
VALUES  ( '19122016', '08012017' ),
        ( '26122016', '01012017' );

select 'select *
    into umkp.dbp.rosk_'+last_date+'_seg
    from umkp.dbp.rosk_'+previous_date+'_seg'
FROM @dates;
```

Comment: It returns only 2 rows with "select *
    into umkp.dbo.rosk_sas_crm_scoring_vector_15012017_seg_base
    from umkp.dbo.sas_crm_scoring_vector_08012017_seg_base" values. May I add something to create  2 tables instead?

Comment: For each row in the `@dates` table variable, there will be one resulting row with target tables according to the last_date column.

Comment: You need to insert all your dates into the `@dates` table variable

Comment: Yes, but I don't catch how to realize that. For example, using local variables, we can change script which create new table:  [declare  last_date varchar(10),  previous_date varchar(10),  sql varchar(max),  sql_some varchar(max);

set  last_date ='20170122';
set  previous_date = '20170108';

set  sql = 'select *
into [UMKP].[dbo].sas_vector_'+ last_date+'_pd_portf_final_dep
from [UMKP].[dbo].sas_vector_'+ previous_date+'_pd_portf_final_dep';

exec( sql)]